# CRC 32 Mysql and CRC32 python?

Tags: python, mysql, zlib

i don't known ? help me

In mysql i run :

```
SELECT CRC32('test');
```

result =  3632233996

In python :

```
import zlib
print zlib.crc32('test')
result = -662733300
```

please help me!

Answer (score 2):

These are actually the same number.

3632233996 = D87F7E0C

-662733300 = FFFFFFFFD87F7E0C

(the number of leading F's depend on your artitecture)

This should fix it for you

```
result = zlib.crc32('test') & 0xFFFFFFFF
```